# Title bar buttons too big, and not in order, on Firefox

Tags: arch-linux, kde, plasma

Excuse my English.

The title bar buttons (close, maximize and minimize) have appeared too big, and not in order, in Firefox on Plasma 5.20.4.

The size is corrected when I enable the title bar in Firefox, but the order is still wrong, and I don't want a title bar on Firefox.

Here are photos:

How it should be:
[image: How it should be]

vs.

How it is on Firefox:
[image: How it is on Firefox]